# I am unable to get urwid work

Tags: python, urwid

I can not get urwid "hello world" example work. I tried with urwid 1.1.1, 1.2.1, with python 2.7.6, 3.4.0, installation via pip, on clean install ubuntu 13.10, 14.04, I still have this output error:

```
7 [?47h
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/neo/hello.py", line 6, in <module>
File "/home/neo/urwid/main_loop.py", line 274, in run
self.screen.run_wrapper(self._run)
File "/home/neo/urwid/raw_display.py", line 267, in run_wrapper
self.start(alternate_buffer)
File "/home/neo/urwid/raw_display.py", line 201, in start
fd = self._term_input_file.fileno()
UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

The runned code:

```
import urwid
txt = urwid.Text(u"Hello World")
fill = urwid.Filler(txt, 'top')
loop = urwid.MainLoop(fill)
loop.run()
```

Comment: what is hello.py? I don't see it in urwid distribution. please provide code

Answer (score 1):

Wardi replied me on  [GitHub](https://github.com/wardi/urwid/issues/69) this:

****urwid needs a real terminal, which IDLE doesn't have. Try running the examples from a terminal instead.****